# ActiveRecord - validation for image url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like for the user to submit a form and fill in a field for 'image_url'. Is there any way I can check validations in the object model to require that the input in the image_url field has an extension of .png or .jpg?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression validation:

```
validates :image_url, format: {with: /\.(png|jpg)\Z/i}
```